# Installing Qt Quick Desktop Components for use in Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer, qt-quick

I'm trying to make the desktop qt-components http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-components/desktop work inside Qt Designer. I'm trying to make the components appear under the "Items" list.

I successfully compiled it using `qmake && mingw32-make install`. This also copied all component files into `\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\imports\QtDesktop`.

I am able to include the components in the editor using `import QtDesktop 0.1`. The following code correctly compiles, runs, and shows a button:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import QtDesktop 0.1

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    Button {
        id: button
        text: "Push me"
        onClicked: button.text = "Pressed"
    }
}
```

[image: Running example]

However when I click on "Design" to enter the Qt Designer, it tries to load for a while and Qt Creator crashes. I've tried this on both Windows and Fedora with the same result.

I've also tried moving the components folder to `\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\imports\Qt\labs\components` but this did not work.

**Update:**
I've tried using qmlplugindump to generate the plugins.qmltypes file per these instruction: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-qml-modules-with-plugins.html but was still unsuccessful. To do this I had to change the `qt-components-desktop\src\src.pro` file to build in release mode with `CONFIG += release` or else qmlplugindump will throw an error. The output plugins.qmltypes file looks good and is located in the same folder as the qmldir file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was reported to Qt's bug database and is expected to be fixed in Qt Creator version 2.5.0 https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-7289